# (Python) ImportError: cannot import name 'SemLock' from '_multiprocessing'

Tags: python, python-3.x, build, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to build a Python 3.8 interpreter on a Red Hat Linux shared server. The compiler builds and executes programs except those that require the Posix named semaphore operations. These would be, for example, the `ThreadPoolExecutor` class from the `concurrent.futures` module or the `Queue` class from the `multiprocessing` module. The exception is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/friendv0/Python3/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 28, in <module>
    from _multiprocessing import SemLock, sem_unlink
ImportError: cannot import name 'SemLock' from '_multiprocessing' (/home/friendv0/Python3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_multiprocessing.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./temp.py", line 53, in <module>
    main()
  File "./temp.py", line 30, in main
    tasks_to_accomplish = Queue()
  File "/home/friendv0/Python3/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 103, in Queue
    return Queue(maxsize, ctx=self.get_context())
  File "/home/friendv0/Python3/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 39, in __init__
    from .synchronize import SEM_VALUE_MAX as maxsize
  File "/home/friendv0/Python3/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 30, in <module>
    raise ImportError("This platform lacks a functioning sem_open" +
ImportError: This platform lacks a functioning sem_open implementation, therefore, the required synchronization primitives needed will not function, see issue 3770.
```

**But I know for a fact that there is a functioning `sem_open` implementation on the platform. I downloaded from Github, compiled and successfully executed the following `C` program (shown only in part):**

```
#include <stdio.h>          /* printf()                 */
#include <stdlib.h>         /* exit(), malloc(), free() */
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>      /* key_t, sem_t, pid_t      */
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>        /* shmat(), IPC_RMID        */
#include <errno.h>          /* errno, ECHILD            */
#include <semaphore.h>      /* sem_open(), sem_destroy(), sem_wait().. */
#include <fcntl.h>          /* O_CREAT, O_EXEC          */


int main (int argc, char **argv){
    int i;                        /*      loop variables          */
    key_t shmkey;                 /*      shared memory key       */
    int shmid;                    /*      shared memory id        */
    sem_t *sem;                   /*      synch semaphore         *//*shared */
    pid_t pid;                    /*      fork pid                */
    int *p;                       /*      shared variable         *//*shared */
    unsigned int n;               /*      fork count              */
    unsigned int value;           /*      semaphore value         */

    /* initialize a shared variable in shared memory */
    shmkey = ftok ("/dev/null", 5);       /* valid directory name and a number */

    /*
      code elided
    */

    /* initialize semaphores for shared processes */
    sem = sem_open ("pSem", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0644, value);
    /* name of semaphore is "pSem", semaphore is reached using this name */
    sem_unlink ("pSem");
```

The above program was compiled with the `-pthread` flag.

I reviewed my Python installation. From the `config.log`:

```
configure:11488: checking for sem_open
configure:11488: gcc -pthread -o conftest  -I /home1/friendv0/local/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include -L/home/friendv0/openssl/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/friendv0/openssl/lib conftest.c -lpthread -ldl  >&5
configure:11488: $? = 0
configure:11488: result: yes
```

And from the `Makefile`:

```
CC=             gcc -pthread
CXX=            g++ -pthread
```

I even did a clean and rebuild to ensure the correct compiler flags were being used. The only thing I can think of is that it is not loading/linking the correct `C` runtime libraries.

**Does anyone have an idea as to what would be causing this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the C program that I downloaded from Github that uses semaphores in fact did not work; it never checked the return value from `sem_open`, which was `SEM_FAILED`.

I checked my configure log more closely and I missed the following:

```
configure:14565: checking whether POSIX semaphores are enabled
configure:14594: gcc -pthread -o conftest  -I /home1/friendv0/local/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include -L/home/friendv0/local/lib64 conftest.c -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm >&5
configure:14594: $? = 0
configure:14594: ./conftest
sem_open: Permission denied
configure:14594: $? = 1
configure: program exited with status 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define _GNU_SOURCE 1
| #define _NETBSD_SOURCE 1
| #define __BSD_VISIBLE 1

/* many lines elided */

| /* end confdefs.h.  */
|
| #include <unistd.h>
| #include <fcntl.h>
| #include <stdio.h>
| #include <semaphore.h>
| #include <sys/stat.h>
|
| int main(void) {
|   sem_t *a = sem_open("/autoconf", O_CREAT, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR, 0);
|   if (a == SEM_FAILED) {
|     perror("sem_open");
|     return 1;
|   }
|   sem_close(a);
|   sem_unlink("/autoconf");
|   return 0;
| }
|
```

After doing some research it appears that the above *Permission denied* error can be caused by not having write access to `/dev/shm` (named semaphores use shared memory and I am on a shared server). The current attributes of that directory are:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root          40 Jul 23 02:20 shm
```

The tricky bit will be convincing my ISP that giving write access to users is not a security issue.